# Should EventAggregator be used for point to point or broadcast messaging

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am using the [`EventAggregator`](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator&referringTitle=Documentation) in Caliburn.Micro in a Windows Phone 8 App.

There are a number of places where the view-models implement `IHandle<SomeClass>`.

My Question is since multiple classes will be handling when an object of `SomeClass` is published, even though they may not be the intended recipient. So what is the best way to deal with this....

1. Design message classes with different names *(but essentially the same content)* so that all communication between view-models is strictly point-to-point ?
2. Or put a source property in message classes so that all receivers know the source of the message so that it can be conditionally processed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no right or wrong answer to this question. As I see it:

1. There are cases when you want point-to-point and it is okay to have a specific message type (class) for solely this purpose
2. There are cases when you want an event like (broadcast) behavior
3. You can also have broadcast with active cancellation just like the one you have in `System.Threading.Task`, or like the one in the WPF eventing model where each handler is a visitor and can set the Handled flag of an event argument (say SomeClass) to true so that the other handler know they shouldn't be processing it anymore.

Also the name `EventAggregator` typically points to the fact that it's most common use is to aggregate handlers i.e. do broadcasting (at least this is how I see it)

Think about the WPF eventing model as an analogy.. You raise the event (publish it) but don't really care about how many handlers you have or what they are doing.